# Implement js function in php code

Tags: javascript, php, toggle

Guys I rely need some help with implementig a js function in a php code. What I want to achieve you can find in the first code, the html one and what I have done in php do the same thing is the second one.

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <script type="text/javascript">

       function toggle_visibility(id) {
           var e = document.getElementById(id);
           if (e.style.display == 'block') e.style.display = 'none';
           else e.style.display = 'block';
       }

   </script>
   <style> 
   #foo1 {
       list-style-type: none;
       padding-bottom:10px;
       display: none;
   }
   #foo2 {
       list-style-type: none;
       padding-bottom:10px;
       display: none;
   }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h3>Programs</h3>

   <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo1');">Movies</a>

   <div id="foo1">
       <ul style="padding-bottom:15px;list-style-type: none;">
           <li style="padding-bottom:15px;"><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://kickass.to/the-official-uk-top-40-singles-chart-15-06-2014-t9225052.html" onclick="this.color=#FF0000;"> _Movie~2014-06-16-1808-name-muzic--1.0.1-4035-g0d107d0~Host</a>

           </li>
           <li style="padding-bottom:15px;"><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://kickass.to/the-official-uk-top-40-singles-chart-15-06-2014-t9225052.html" onclick="this.color=#FF0000;"> _Movie~2014-06-16-1808-name-muzic--1.0.1-4035-g0d107d0~Host</a>

           </li>
           <li style="padding-bottom:15px;"><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://kickass.to/the-official-uk-top-40-singles-chart-15-06-2014-t9225052.html" onclick="this.color=#FF0000;"> _Movie~2014-06-16-1808-name-muzic--1.0.1-4035-g0d107d0~Host</a>

           </li>
       </ul>
   </div>

   <br><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo2');">Music</a>
   <div id="foo2">
   <ul style="padding-bottom:15px;list-style-type: none;">
           <li style="padding-bottom:15px;"><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://kickass.to/game-of-thrones-s04e10-720p-hdtv-x264-killers-rartv-t9225859.html" onclick="this.color=#FF0000;"> _Muzic~2014-06-16-1808-name-muzic--1.0.1-4035-g0d107d0~Host</a>

           </li>
           <li style="padding-bottom:15px;"><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://kickass.to/game-of-thrones-s04e10-720p-hdtv-x264-killers-rartv-t9225859.html" onclick="this.color=#FF0000;"> _Muzic~2014-06-16-1808-name-muzic--1.0.1-4035-g0d107d0~Host</a>

           </li>
           <li style="padding-bottom:15px;"><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://kickass.to/game-of-thrones-s04e10-720p-hdtv-x264-killers-rartv-t9225859.html" onclick="this.color=#FF0000;"> _Muzic~2014-06-16-1808-name-muzic--1.0.1-4035-g0d107d0~Host</a>
                </li>
       </ul>
   </div>


   </body></html>
```

So what I am trying to achieve is this, I have a folder, lets say Folder1 and in this folder I have 3 subfolders lets say Subfolder1, Subfolder2 and Subfolder3 and each of these 3 subfolders I have 5 files that need to be downloaded. I want to create 3 links that are toggles for the downloading links. So I will have 3 toggle links called Subfolder1, Subfolder2 and Subfolder3. aND when you click them using a js function you change the display property of the subfolder for each of the folder links. So if you click Subfolder1 it will expand and show the download links for the 5 documents.
And the name of one file from the Subfolder1 is testDownload1.exe, so the link will have the name of the parent folder concatenated with the name of the file that will be downloaded. So the name will be: Subfolder1_testDownloaded

```
<?
    if (isset($_POST['password']))
    {
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $goodPass = '******';
        if ($password == $goodPass)
            $_SESSION['loggedIn']=1;
        }
        if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) 
            showPasswordForm();
        else
        {
           $install_links = getDirectory(".");
           rsort($install_links);
           $oldPrefix = "";
           foreach ($install_links as $key => $val) 
           {
               $strip_val = strip_tags($val);

               $prefix = explode("~",$strip_val);
               //echo "Prefix:|".$prefix[0]."|</br>";
               if (strcmp($prefix[0],$oldPrefix)!=0)
                  echo <<<EOT </div> <a href='#'            onclick="toggle_visibility('".$prefix[0]."');"> "".$prefix[0].""</a><div id="".$prefix[0]."">EOT;
                  $oldPrefix = $prefix[0];
                  echo '<li style="padding-bottom:15px">'.$val.'</li><br/>';
            }
        }

   function getDirectory( $path = '.', $level = 0 ){ 

       $echoData = false;

       $protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://";
       $root_folder_url_prefix = $protocol.".....";

       $ignore = array( 'cgi-bin', '.', '..','WHat.app.dSYM' ); 
       // Directories to ignore when listing output. Many hosts 
       // will deny PHP access to the cgi-bin. 

       $dh = @opendir( $path ); 
       // Open the directory to the handle $dh 

       $install_links = array();

       while( false !== ( $file = readdir( $dh ) ) ){ 
       // Loop through the directory 

           if( !in_array( $file, $ignore ) ){ 
           // Check that this file is not to be ignored 

               $spaces = str_repeat( '&nbsp;', ( $level * 4 ) ); 
               // Just to add spacing to the list, to better 
               // show the directory tree. 

               if( is_dir( "$path/$file" ) ){ 
               // Its a directory, so we need to keep reading down... 

                   if ( $echoData) 
                      echo "<strong>$spaces $file</strong><br />"; 
                      $subarray = getDirectory( "$path/$file", ($level+1) ); 

                      $install_links = array_merge($install_links, $subarray);
                      // Re-call this same function but on a new directory. 
                      // this is what makes function recursive. 

               } else { 
                   if (strstr($file,".ipa"))
                   {
                       //echo ">>".$file."<<";
                       $filename = str_replace(".ipa","",$file);
                       $plist_path = substr($path,2);
                       $plist_path = str_replace("/","~",$plist_path);
                       $plist_location =            $root_folder_url_prefix.$plist_path."~".$filename.".plist";
                       $link = '<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url='.$plist_location.'"  onclick="this.color=#FF0000;"> '.$plist_path.'-'.$filename.'</a>';

                       if ( $echoData) 
                           echo "$spaces $link<br/>";

                       array_push($install_links,$link);

                   }
                   else             
                   {
                       //   echo "$spaces $file<br />"; 
                       // Just print out the filename 
                   }
               } 

           } 

       } 

       closedir( $dh ); 
       // Close the directory handle 

       return $install_links;
   }




   function showPasswordForm()
   {
?>
   <center>
   <form action="index.php" method="post">
   <table>
   <tr><td>User:</td>  <td> <input type="text" name="user" /></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Password:</td> <td> <input type="password" name="password" /></td></tr>
   <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>           </tr>
   </table>
   </form> 
   </center>
<?
   }

?>
```

Comment: Two things this site is not 1. do my coding for free 2.debugging my code for free, I am to lazy. Identify the area of the code where you have a problem. Generate relevant dumps of variables/arrays etc so we can see whats going in and whats coming out. In otherwords, show you have tried to fix it yourself. You could also try tidying your code so it is easily readable.

Comment: So I need help here:
       echo <<<EOT </div> <a href='#'                                        onclick="toggle_visibility('".$prefix[0]."');"> "".$prefix[0].""</a>       <div id="".$prefix[0]."">EOT;
           $oldPrefix = $prefix[0];
               echo '<li style="padding-bottom:15px">'.$val.'</li><br/>';
       }

Comment: Look at the manual page. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc Check your syntax with the section titled `invalid syntax` and there you have your answer.

Comment: PHP is a sever-sided language, meant for HTML generation and database access. It is run only on page load and not again until you reload (or use Ajax). Basically there is absolutely no reason to implement that JavaScript function as a PHP one.

Comment: Spencer Wieczorek, so what you are saying is that I should load the page just with what I am interested, using a # link, not realize a proper js toggle effect, right?

Comment: I said the exact opposite of that: "no reason to implement that JavaScript function as a PHP one". For what reason would you want to do a toggle effect in PHP, if you could do it in JavaScript?

Comment: and how will you call the js function in a index.php file?

Comment: In exactly the same way as in your HTML file. A PHP file acts the same as an HTML file, only in an PHP file you can use PHP code. That is the only difference.